# Rails Koala gem how to post a link to my page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, koala, koala-gem

I can post a message to my page using this, but how do I post a url, with an image and a link to the url.
@page.put_connections('me', "feed", {:message => "Page writting to dduser's wallxxxcdcds!"})

Answer (score 2):

`@page.put_wall_post("body", {link: "www.google.com", caption: "caption"})`